# Observe Kotlin StateFlow from Background service's companion object

Tags: android, android-service, kotlin-flow

Are there any cons of using Kotlin state flow in companion object for checking if background service is running?
I wanted to use ActivityManager and its function `isServiceRunning(Service::class.name)`, but this method is deprecated.
By the way, I should be observing this service from Fragment/Fragment's ViewModel, so I wanted to avoid Binding the service to Activity.

```
class TestService : Service() {
     companion object {
            private val _testStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<TestServiceEvent>()
            val testServiceStateFlow = _testStateFlow.asStateFlow()
     }

     override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
            _testStateFlow.value = TestServiceEvent.ServiceRunning(true)
            ....
            ....
            ....
            ....
            _testStateFlow.value = TestServiceEvent.TestTaskDone()
     }

     override fun onDestroy(){
          super.onDestroy()
          _testStateFlow.value = TestServiceEvent.ServiceRunning(false)
     }


     sealed class TestServiceEvent{
          data class ServiceRunning(val isRunning : Boolean) : TestServiceEvent()
          object TestTaskDone : TestServiceEvent()
     }
}
```

Comment: have you figure out the behaviour?

Comment: To be honest I didn't have a chance to use it in production, because of additional requirements I received... 
Except for these (Flow) objects staying in memory for as long as the app is alive I don't see any other downside of this approach.

Comment: thanks for sharing, turnout I didn't put the Flow/ SharedFlow in companion object, instead bind the Fragment to the Service, then it's able to observe it as expected, just have to take care the lifecycle of both Fragment and Service well